# The best way to get the next record of the same table in a subquery

Tags: mysql

I have the following table. 
[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/93f5d9/1) 
[image]

I would like to obtain the time of the next value other than 20 for ocx_co selected
The result would be 
[image]

 
The problem is that the explain is throwing me that to obtain that value has to consult several records. 
[image]

Is there a possibility that I would only select the largest record without having to traverse the entire table?

Comment: Honestly, this query looks fine. It's using indexes, so it shouldn't be impacted by full scan lookups, and I don't see any issues.

Comment: Thank you @FrankerZ  Well, but in an environment where there are thousands of records, performance may fall. There is no way for it to be 
40 > 1?

Comment: This query should work efficiently with millions of rows

Comment: Thank you @FrankerZ